# Fulltext search with partial strings on Postgresql

Tags: database, performance, postgresql, full-text-search

I was assigned to develop a full-text search functionality on PostgreSql 9.3 and I'd be very glad if I can hear other opinions and advices in this matter.

The problem is, that I need to implement a partial word match. An user will send out a string which can contain partial words, separated by space, and without order.

For example: string "lue ped zeb" should find a row with "Blue striped zebra" in it (in one column). It should be case-insensitive and the order of words should not matter (but these conditions are insignificant in this question).

Problem is performance. There are over 5 million rows in the database table on which the search is performed and I need to get to very small execution times.

Example query would be "SELECT * FROM table WHERE LOWER(text) LIKE ('%lue%ped%zeb');", which I suspect will be VERY slow because the wildcard at first position will cause the query to ignore indexes.

So far, I've found http://www.sai.msu.su/~megera/wiki/wildspeed, which is a index that could help me (size of the index doesn't really matter in this case), but the production server is running MS Windows and I don't know if this extension will be able to compile on windows. (I will try it and update my question).

I'm not a database developer and use Postgres usually only from applications, so I don't have much experience in database optimalization and lower-level operations.

Does anyone have some experience with similar problem, word of advice or example that can help me with this task?

Comment: The problem is, what you've described is not a google-like full text search (f.ex. google won't find *zebra*, if you are looking for *zeb*). But, there **is** a real full text search support in Postgres: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/textsearch.html

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply! I'm sorry, the comparsion to google wasn't correct. I am aware of the postgresql full-text search capabilities (vaguely), but that isn't exactly what I'm looking for. I really need the partial words match as stated above (return "Zebra" for "ebr")

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Trigram](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgtrgm.html) is a contrib module for Postgres, which can help you achieve your goal. There is a complete example of its usage in the docs.

Beginning in 9.1, trigram support index searches for `LIKE` and `ILIKE` operators.

Beginning in 9.3, it support index searches for regular-expression matches (`~` and `~*` operators).

But if you want to search for any order of the provided *partial words*, you should query for each word separate:

```
...
WHERE LOWER(text) LIKE '%lue%'
   OR LOWER(text) LIKE '%ped%'
   OR LOWER(text) LIKE '%zeb%'
```

Comment: Thanks very much! Trigram seems like it could solve my problem and I will definitely test it. I will post my results here when I'am done.

Comment: Ok, so I tried the Trigram extension and it really works in the way I need it to. Thanks - you saved me a lot of time!